# JavaFX Null Pointer Exception: Location is required

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

JavaFX newbie here. I am using NetBeans 8.0 IDE and I placed my FXML file **RootLayout.fxml** in `com.techie.java.view` package. I am loading this fxml file using the following code declared in `com.techie.java.controller` package:

```
private void initRootLayout() {
    try {
        pane = FXMLLoader.load(ContactManager.class.getResource("/view/RootLayout.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    } catch (IOException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void showPersonOverview() {
    try {
        AnchorPane anchorPane = FXMLLoader.load(ContactManager.class.getResource("/view/PersonOverview.fxml"));

        pane.setCenter(anchorPane);
    } catch (IOException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

While executing I am getting Null pointer exception at `BorderPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(ContactManager.class.getResource("/view/RootLayout.fxml"));`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what line is the error occurring at?

Comment: What does `getResource()` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
pane = FXMLLoader.load(
    ContactManager.class.getResource("/com/techie/java/view/RootLayout.fxml"));
```

and similarly for the other `FXMLLoader`.